# How to use Charts in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, charts

Im new to Flex and Actionscript (2 weeks).

I'm trying to use a Chart whose DataProvider is an ArrayCollection that contains Objects
'Person' for example. Person's properties are Age and Salary.

My chart will be an ColumnChart and the xField=Age and the yField would be the AVG(or SUM) Salary for Persons with the same age.

There is any easy way to do that?
Using the way I've just learned, each Person will own one Column in the chart.

My mxml code:

```
< mx :ColumnChart id="myChart" height="100%" color="0x323232"
showDataTips="true" dataProvider="{GraphArray}">

        < mx:series>

                < mx:ColumnSeries xField="age" yField="salary"/>

        < /mx:series>

< /mx:ColumnChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the standard charts will only display exactly what you give them, so you'll need to create a new data provider that contains the average/sum of the data for each age group.

To make a derived provider that stays up to date with changes to GraphArray, you can either add listeners to GraphArray or, if the GraphArray is only set and not modified, you can get away with breaking the variable out into getters and setters, something like this (untested) code:

If you had

```
[Bindable]
public var GraphArray:ArrayCollection;
```

Replace it with

```
private var _GraphArray:ArrayCollection;
[Bindable]
private var DerivedGraphArray:ArrayCollection;

[Bindable]
public function get GraphArray():ArrayCollection
{
    return _GraphArray;
}

public function set GraphArray(value:ArrayCollection):void
{
    var ageBucketedArray:Array = new Array(121);
    var ageBucketedCountsArray:Array = new Array(121);

    //Compute salary sums
    for each (var o:Object in value)
    {
        if (ageBucketedArray[o["age"]])
        {
            ageBucketedArray[o["age"]] += o["salary"];
            ageBucketedCountsArray[o["age"]] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ageBucketedArray[o["age"]] = o["salary"];
            ageBucketedCountsArray[o["age"]] = 1;
        }
    }


    //Compute averages
    for (var age:int = 0; age < ageBucketedArray.length; age++)
    {
        if (ageBucketedArray[age])
        {
            ageBucketedArray[age] /= ageBucketedCountsArray[age];
        }
        else
        {
            ageBucketedArray[age] = 0;
        }
    }

    _GraphArray.removeAll();
    _GraphArray.addAll(value);
    DerivedGraphArray = new ArrayCollection(ageBucketedArray);
}
```